# Linux - Diff number of lines in 2 set of files

Tags: linux

I have 2 folders which contains 2 set of files.

Folder1

```
input1.csv
input2.csv
...
```

Folder2

```
output1.json
output2.json
...
```

Ideally, the number of lines in input1 should be same as output1, the number of lines in input2 should be same as output2, and so on.

I need a Linux command to check this automatically and tell me which files are different.

Basically,

```
If wc -l input1 == wc -l output1, 
    then skip;
else
    show input1 file name (or output1 file name)

repeat for all other files.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: On Linux/Unix/BSD, these are called "directories" and not the Windows user concept of "folders".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this might help

```
arr=("1.in" "2.in")
arr2=("1.out" "2.out")

for i in ${!arr[@]}; do  
  v_in=$(wc -l < ${arr[$i]}) ; 
  v_out= $(wc -l < ${arr2[$i]}) ;

  if [ v_in -ne v_out ] then
     echo "not equal"
  else
     echo "equal"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

- list filenames from both folders
- join the list of both folders with matching filenmaes
- for each two filenames

  - get count of lines
  - compare it

    - "show input1 file name"

The following is some code you can start with:

```
list_sorted_filenames() {
  find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sort
}
paste <(list_filenames "Folder1") <(list_filenames "Folder2") |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r input output; do
   if (( $(wc -l <"$input") != $(wc -l <"$output") )); then
         echo "input=$input
   fi
done
```